# Segregate even and odd nodes in a Linked List with odd node first

Tags: c++, c++11

My code does not display the output .
This is  my question

Given a list, modify it such that all odd elements appear before the even ones. The order of odd elements and even shall remain intact.

Input Format
The first line contains an integer N, the number of elements in the list.

The next line contains N space separated integral elements of the list

Sample Input
5
1 2 3 4 5

Sample Output
1 3 5 2 4

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node *next;
    node (int d)
    {
        data = d;
        next = NULL;
    }

};
void insert(node *&head, node*&tail ,int data)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = tail = new node (data);
        return ;
    }

    else
    {
        node* n = new node(data);
        tail->next = n;
        tail = n;
    }


}
void seg(node *&head)
{
    node *current = head;
    node *estart = NULL;
    node *Eend = NULL;
    node *ostart = NULL;
    node *oend = NULL;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        int value = current->data;
        if (value % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (estart == NULL)
            {
                estart = Eend = current;

            }
            else
            {
                Eend->next = current;
                current = Eend;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (ostart == NULL)
            {
                ostart = oend = current;
            }
            else
            {
                oend->next = current;
                current = oend;
            }
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    if (ostart != NULL)
    {
        head = ostart;
        oend->next = estart;
        Eend->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        head = estart;
        Eend->next = NULL;
    }
}
void print(node *head)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        cout << head->data;
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int m;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cin >> m;
        insert(head, tail, m);
    }
    seg(head);
    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `seg` function is not linking up the nodes correctly. When updating the ends of the even/odd linked-lists, instead of doing

```
Eend->next = current;
current = Eend;
```

and

```
oend->next = current;
current = oend;
```

you need to do

```
Eend = Eend->next = current;
```

and

```
oend = oend->next = current;
```

respectively. This bumps up the ends of the even/odd lists correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a requirement to use your own linked list class, you can do this easily with [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition). Read the numbers into a container such as `std::vector`, and then just do `std::stable_partition(a.begin(), a.end(), [](int x) { return x % 2; })`. That syntax with the square brackets is a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), and it's basically a function literal.